# Why is text in django form validator not translated?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I import translation with

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _
```

and have this Form definition

```
class SearchSubstance(forms.Form):
    search_string = forms.CharField(max_length=100, validators=[validators.MinLengthValidator(4), too_much_compounds_validator])
```

with this custom validator

```
def too_much_compounds_validator(query):
    raise ValidationError(_("translate this"))
```

now the error message of `MinLengthValidator` is nicely translated (in Dutch) but somehow `"translate this"` is not translated. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where did you define the translation? Did you run [`makemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-makemessages) and then [`compilemessages`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-compilemessages)?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I have done that. Where should that be done?